# mvvmcross localization in windows store app

Tags: localization, windows-store-apps, mvvmcross

First, congratulation to the creators of mvvmcross, it´s really amazing....

Now.... I started using mvvmcross in a windows phone and a Windows store App without problems so far, using the demos as guide, I managed to get almost everything up and running, in particular json and sqlite, however I´m having troubles with localization in the windows store Project, I didn´t see a demo for this case, only for the windows phone (that works like a charm)... I thought that it should be similar to the Windows phone, but I dont get it to work, it runs, but it seems that it doesn´t find the .json files..

Are there aditionals steps for localization in a windows store app? (resource location, build actions...) and what about in a wpf app?

Thanks in advance

Roy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's an issue with the store based resource loader - it doesn't like the forward slashes.

I just uploaded Babel Windows Store and Wpf example apps to https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Babel

---

For WindowsStore, there is a bug with back and forward slashes.

To workaround this, in Setup.cs there is a `Hack` fix class:

```
public class HackMvxStoreResourceLoader : MvxStoreResourceLoader
{
    public override void GetResourceStream(string resourcePath, Action<Stream> streamAction)
    {
        // in 3.0.8.2 and earlier we needed to replace the "/" with "\\" :/
        resourcePath = resourcePath.Replace("/", "\\");
        base.GetResourceStream(resourcePath, streamAction);
    }
}

public class Setup : MvxStoreSetup
{
    public Setup(Frame rootFrame) : base(rootFrame)
    {
    }

    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        Mvx.RegisterType<IMvxResourceLoader, HackMvxStoreResourceLoader>();
        return new Core.App();
    }
}
```

I've also added this to https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/332 - should be fixed in a future release.

---

For Wpf, the resource loader should work, but there are some issues in the current released nuget packages which required manual patches of:

- manually add the ResourceLoader.Wpf plugin assembly - see [lib/HACKEDIN_net45](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Babel/packages/MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.ResourceLoader.3.0.8.1/lib/HACKEDIN_net45)
- manually add two Bootstrap classes - see the 'hack' bootstrap classes in [Wpf/Setup.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Babel/Babel.Wpf/Setup.cs)

These missing nuget steps were logged in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/267 - which is marked as fixed - so should be in the next nuget release packages.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and the new demos.. your work (and support) with mvvmcross is excelent...